# Построение графиков онлайн используя функцию JS

Tags: javascript, graph

Вопрос не совсем по теме, но с программированием это частично связано.

Ищу сервис, который на входе через textarea принимает js код, например:

```
return (x) => x * x;
```

Или:

```
return [
     (x) => x * x,
     (x) => x * 2,
];
```

Или:

```
const func = (x) => x * x;
return func;
```

А на выходе он рисует график(и), исходя из того, что возвращает return.

Короче говоря, ищу построитель графиков с полной поддержкой JS.

P.S. Понимаю, что подобное можно и самому сделать, но это вопрос времени и велосипедостроения. Возможно, есть готовое решение, которое я не могу найти.

P.S.S. Любой гугловский поиск просто ведет на JS библиотеки.

---

По идее, тут связка простая: вытягиваем данные из поля, выполняем извлеченный код и [получаем функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7399078/4138135), используем любую библиотеку для построения графиков, применяем функцию к ней. Может быть кто-то это уже сделал и сделал лучше, чем это получилось бы у меня.

Comment: А что вам мешает взять библиотеку и сделать такой сервис. раз его никто еще не сделал? Это совсем не сложный сервис..

Comment: Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: ... Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.*

Comment: @Arhad в любом случае сейчас я ничего сделать не могу. Удалил бы, да не дает. Обычно я не задаю глупых вопросов. Просто так получилось)

Answer (score 2):

Пользовался лично этой библиотекой, довольно удобная:

http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

Пара других:

http://www.cotrino.com/2013/05/starpaths/

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

https://nxsheet.com/sheets/56d0a87264e47ee60a95f652

Тут можно поискать просто из тонн разных вариантов:

https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery

Тут нужно рисовать оси самому:

http://sigmajs.org/

Comment: Задача не в поиске подходящей библиотеки. Задача в построении графика online, используя обычную JS функцию. Помимо прочего, почти все эти библиотеки работают по принципу "массив данных => график", а мне нужно "функция => график" со всеми вытекающими (в особенности интересует маштабирование)

Comment: @ВиталийЗаславский в чем проблема, имея функцию, нагенерировать массив данных? это две-три строки.

Comment: Еще можно упомянуть очень мощную либу http://rrag.github.io/react-stockcharts/ но не уверен, что она сюда подойдет в тему

Comment: @Виталий Заславский я прекрасно это понял. Но здесь не принято решать проблемы за других, тут принято помогать. Покажите свои наработки, как вы пытались это сделать и у вас не сработало и вам определенно помогут. Эти библиотеки по сути решают 90% вашего вопроса.